# sudo mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is busy - skipping

Tags: linux, md

I am able to mount `/dev/md0` device but not `sdc1`.
While mounting sdc1 getting below error.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/s1/
mount: /mnt/s1: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.
janardha@saankhya-virtual-machine:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble
```

Comment: There are many confusing things here. You have RAID inside a virtual machine? And why are you trying to mount component drives directly? This breaks your RAID data.

Comment: In addition to that, please provide the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: Yes, I am trying raid inside virtual Machine. I copied some data to my raid device(/dev/md0), I want to check same data is copied to component drives(/dev/sdc1) or not.


lsblk info: 

sda       8:0    0    96G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0    64G  0 part  /
└─sda2    8:2    0     1M  0 part
sdb       8:16   0    16G  0 disk
└─sdb1    8:17   0   7.2G  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0   7.2G  0 raid1
sdc       8:32   0    16G  0 disk
└─sdc1    8:33   0   7.2G  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0   7.2G  0 raid1

Comment: Raid command I used: 

sudo mdadm --verbose --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1

Comment: lsblk info:


sda       8:0    0    96G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0    64G  0 part  
└─sda2    8:2    0     1M  0 part

sdb       8:16   0    16G  0 disk
└─sdb1    8:17   0   7.2G  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0   7.2G  0 raid1
  
sdc       8:32   0    16G  0 disk
└─sdc1    8:33   0   7.2G  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0   7.2G  0 raid1